# Why shows the effect shown in the video below left-right asymmetry?

Tags: lcd, tft, pressure, movement

I made [this video](https://youtu.be/-Zi0yKl4KHk) which shows what happens when I move the point of a wooden chopstick over my [TFT-LCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display) screen, with firm pressure.

It's remarkable that one can see that there is a difference between moving the chopstick to the right and to the left (with about equal pressure).
When moving the pressure point to the right the blue blob is positioned on the right side of the pressure point (and between the two red "wake" circles), and while moving it to the left it's also on the right side (so the blobs are on the opposite sides of the pressure point's direction of moving).
The pattern has a different colored "tail", dependent on the direction of motion, being green when moving to the left and pinkish when moving to the right.
What's a pronounced difference too, are the yellow structures: When moving to the right there is one in front and one behind the pressure point. When moving to the left there are two yellow concentric "circles" of which the outer one is much fainter. And so on.

I'm sure it's got something to do with the distance between the two glass plates in the LCD part (so the polarization vector of the light is changed, which changes the color). It's strange that the pattern is direction-dependent, though at second thought when moving the pressure point on a flexible, smooth, and flat structure, the pressure is of course not symmetrical distributed around the pressure point. So the pressure on the upper plastic sheet is asymmetrical wrt the moving pressure point, and those nice patterns form because the pressure varies in a continuous way, making the distance between the sheets smaller in a continuous way too. I just wonder why the color distribution is different if going in different directions. The pressure distribution will be the same when moving in both directions (see the answer below, where a comparison is made with the movement of the chopstick on a rubber sheet which is obviously direction independent), won't it?

So why is the pattern dependent on the direction in which I move the pressure point with the chopstick?. Shouldn't the same bulge pop up in front of the moving chopstick, and the same stretching behind it, no matter in which direction I move the chopstick? In other words, why does the effect shows no left-right symmetry?

Comment: it might be best to include the information on what the video is in the post, if the link goes down. Thanks

Comment: @VoltageSpike I tried to put two pictures of the patterns that appear when moving to both directions, to compare them ("search the differences") but it took too much time. But I tried in words. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you were dragging on a rubber sheet instead of the LCD screen. The sheet would stretch out a bit behind the stick and bunch up slightly in front. The pattern would look exactly like what you're seeing on the LCD.

A LCD screen works by changing the polarization of light as it passes through a very narrow gap between 2 plastic sheets. This gap must be very precise, because if the gap changes the polarization will change. As you drag the chopstick around on the screen, you're disturbing the top sheet, which is changing the thickness of the gap. This causes a visual disturbance.